# Combine listeners in Google Maps api v3 with google charts

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### Integrate or mix Listeners from google map api with google chart table

I've created a map with google maps api v3 very simple, explained in code1.

As you can see, at the end of the code there is a Listener waiting for a click to be made on the marker/symbol to show the name of the marker.

Also I have a table (explained in code 2) made with Google Chart that have info related to the map.

What I need (and can't find) is when I click either the map or the table, the content related to it has to be highlighted/selected.

Clues/Tips:

- Use new_map as global variable (didn't work)
- how different is google.maps from google.visualization?
- Has to be made with google.maps, because maps from google.visualization don't let rotate the markers.

**** I Will give special points :) ****

### code1(Google Map Api):

```
function init_nuevo_mapa() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5351136, -70.5876618)
    };

    var new_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('new-map'), mapOptions);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5351136, -70.5876618)
    var image = {
        path: 'M 0,0 -10,-30 10,-30 z',
        rotation: 10, //10º clockwise
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        scale: 1,
        strokeColor: "red",
        strokeWeight: 4
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        zIndex: zIndex,
        title: location[2]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(13);
        alert(marker.getTitle());
        alert(marker.getPosition());
        //marker.setVisible(false);
    });
}
```

### Code 2(Google Chart Table):

```
 function drawChart() {
        var datos_resumen = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datos_resumen.addColumn('string', 'Acción');
        datos_resumen.addColumn('string', 'Celda');
        datos_resumen.addColumn('number', 'Prioridad actual');
        datos_resumen.addColumn('number', 'Prioridad nueva');
        datos_resumen.addColumn('number', 'Distancia [km]');

        datos_resumen.addRow([
            "Cambiar",
        resultado_vecino[i][2],
        resultado_vecino[i][3],
        resultado_vecino[i][4],
        Number(resultado_vecino[i][6].toPrecision(3))]);

        var tabla_resumen = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('resumen_div'));
        tabla_resumen.draw(datos_resumen, {
            showRowNumber: true
        });


        google.visualization.events.addListener(tabla_resumen, 'select', selectHandler);

        function selectHandler(e) {
            var selected = tabla_resumen.getSelection()[0];
            if (selected) {
                var celda = datos_resumen.getValue(selected.row, 1)

                alert(celda);

                var temp = $.ajax({
                    url: 'sql_coord_cell.php?celda=' + celda,
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                var js_geo_data = JSON.parse(temp);

                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(js_geo_data['lat'], js_geo_data['lon']);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                infowindow.setOptions({
                    content: celda,
                    position: location
                });
                infowindow.open()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete, Tested** and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The posted code has syntax errors and is missing data for the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it.

I just had to define a empty global variable outside functions like this

```
var new_map;
```

because this wont work:

```
var new_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('new-map'), mapOptions);
```

With this I can access to the map object from others object to interact between them